# How to set the order of the values in multi-select dropdown:jQuery chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the jquery chosen for multi select.

I have a case where i need to remember the order of the options that are being selected and display it in same order.

When I select option from dropdown, order of the selected options will be same as in which order i selected from dropdown(this is fine), but, say I went to some other page of the application and came back to this page(which has multi-select dropdown), then i need to show the options(options being selected) in same order as they were selected.

I even tried with $(".chosen").val(), but result of this also was not in the order of selection, instead it is in the order of options in dropdown.

So, is there any way to set the order of the selected options in multi select.

Comment: I don't know about chosen, but I use the combotree component of the EasyUI, and the result is in order of selection... Maybe be a alternative to you...